# MarshalJSON a type with an embedded type ends up as {} instead of the value

Tags: json, go, struct, embedding

To interact with swagger, I needed to make a custom `BigInt` struct which does nothing more than wrap around go's `big.Int`.

```
type BigInt struct {
    big.Int
}

...
type SpendTx struct {
    SenderID    string       `json:"sender_id,omitempty"`
    RecipientID string       `json:"recipient_id,omitempty"`
    Amount      utils.BigInt `json:"amount,omitempty"`
    Fee         utils.BigInt `json:"fee,omitempty"`
    Payload     string       `json:"payload,omitempty"`
    TTL         uint64       `json:"ttl,omitempty"`
    Nonce       uint64       `json:"nonce,omitempty"`
}

func (t SpendTx) JSON() (output []byte, err error) {
    return json.Marshal(t)
}
```

I'd expect `SpendTx.JSON()` to eventually call `big.Int.MarshalJSON()`, which would return `0`. Instead, I got this output:

`{"sender_id":"alice","recipient_id":"bob","amount":{},"fee":{},"payload":"Hello World","ttl":10,"nonce":1}`

But what I really want is this:

`{"sender_id":"alice","recipient_id":"bob","amount":10,"fee":10,"payload":"Hello World","ttl":10,"nonce":1}`

And I had to add this bit of code to `BigInt` to do it:

```
func (b BigInt) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return b.Int.MarshalJSON()
}
```

But according to [Effective Go's section on embedding structs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding), this shouldn't be necessary at all. Why is `big.Int` appearing as as `{}`?

Comment: MarshalJSON is declared on a pointer to `BigInt` that's why it's not called automatically when you pass a *value* to json.Marshal, you can fix this by passing a pointer to `json.Marshal`. https://play.golang.org/p/HQV4eJVwmeE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) implements a custom JSON marshaler ([`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler)), see [`Int.MarshalJSON()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.MarshalJSON). But this method has pointer receiver, so it is only used / called, if you have a pointer value: `*big.Int`.

And you embed a non-pointer value, so this custom marshaler is not called, and since `big.Int` is a struct with unexported fields, you will see an empty JSON object in the output: `{}`.

To make it work, you should use a pointer to your type, e.g.:

```
Amount      *utils.BigInt `json:"amount,omitempty"`
Fee         *utils.BigInt `json:"fee,omitempty"`
```

Example using it:

```
s := SpendTx{
    SenderID:    "alice",
    RecipientID: "bob",
    Amount:      &utils.BigInt{},
    Fee:         &utils.BigInt{},
}
data, err := s.JSON()
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Then output will be for example (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4OoQDP-wAAG)):

```
{"sender_id":"alice","recipient_id":"bob","amount":0,"fee":0} <nil>
```

Another option is to use the non-pointer `utils.BigInt`, but then `utils.BigInt` should embed a pointer type:

```
type BigInt struct {
    *big.Int
}

type SpendTx struct {
    Amount      utils.BigInt `json:"amount,omitempty"`
    Fee         utils.BigInt `json:"fee,omitempty"`
}
```

And then using it:

```
s := SpendTx{
    SenderID:    "alice",
    RecipientID: "bob",
    Amount:      utils.BigInt{new(big.Int)},
    Fee:         utils.BigInt{new(big.Int)},
}
data, err := s.JSON()
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

And output will be again (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6aSBA6oHB8t)):

```
{"sender_id":"alice","recipient_id":"bob","amount":0,"fee":0} <nil>
```